# Add library to CMakeLists

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I am very new to ROS and I trying to include a library eigen-eigen-67e894c6cd8f which is available in /usr/local/include to the CMakeLists.txt.  I have tried doing the below command but I have had no success. I am able to use this library outside ros and it works fine. However, when I do catkin_make it throws a bunch of errors. My package is named "my_pcl" and "test" is my executable. Thanks in advance

include_directories(/usr/local/include/eigen-eigen-67e894c6cd8f)
add_executable(test eigen-eigen-67e894c6cd8f)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260641/add-library-to-cmakelists/) by [vin25](https://answers.ros.org/users/30202/vin25/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

System-wide libraries are resolved by `CMake` relative to  `/usr/local/lib` if you are using a 32-bit architecture machine or `/usr/local/lib64` if you are on a 64-bit architecture.

Something seems wrong with the location where your library is domiciled. Either fix this by copying the appropriate library file over to `usr/local/lib` or manually tell `cmake` to look in `usr/local/include`. The first option is more standard and I would choose that over the latter.

---

Originally posted by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) with karma: 152 on 2017-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0